# How to set up code formatting in Kdevelop with clang-format?

Tags: clang-format, kdevelop

I'm trying to set up code formatting in Kdevelop 5.4.5. I click on Settings > Configure KDevelop > Source Code Formatter. In the **Formatter** dropdown I select **Custom Script Formatter**, select **Clang Format** in the options listbox, then click on the **New** button.

When I go to edit my newly created formatter, this is displayed:

[image]

I tried running the "command" in the project's root directory, but nothing happens.

How do I create my own formatting style in KDevelop using clang-format?

Answer (score 3):

There are bugs. Add parameter **-style=file**, after add your own .clang-format file in project root directory and add "$FILE" at the end of command line and it will work, but soon you will discover new problems, for example with headers.

Use **external scripts** window in KDevelop. Call **clang-format** with your own parameters, add hotkey for it and be happy.